# Call JQuery Function OnClick

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I know this question looks very similar to other questions on this site but I'm in a particular situation and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this to work. Perhaps it's simple but I can't figure it out. This is my basic dialog function that I want to call onclick with an "a" tag:

```
<script>
     $('<iframe src="hyperlink" id="tag" frameBorder="0" width="98%" />').dialog({
          autoOpen:false,
          title: 'Documents',
          modal:true,
          autoResize:true,
          resizable:false,
          width: 900,
          height: 400,
          draggable:false,
          open: function(){
               $(this).css('width','98%'
               );
          }
     });
```

I know using iframes isn't preferable but there's a very specific reason that this is the only way it will work. Apart from that, how could I get a tex to call this dialog box onclick?

Comment: Does the posted code work and you just want to know how to call it on click of an anchor tag?

Comment: Thank you, yes, the code works onload when I remove the autoOpen line.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$("a#thelink").click(function(){
   $("#tag").dialog('open');
});
```

where `thelink` is the ID of your link.

Comment: No luck... fyi, my anchor tag is as follows: <a href="#" id="thelink">text</a>

Comment: @kingjiv +1 Got your fiddle to load iframe by changing iframe src to yahoo.com. Thanks to both you and kramden88 for teaching me something new.

Comment: It certainly does work, thank you. There must be something else wrong on the page. I'll have to investigate but I do appreciate your help!

Comment: For any future visitors with a problem like mine (i.e. the code looks good but just won't run onclick) try adding  $(window).load(function(){ before the first line. This got it working for me at long last!

Comment: Thanks again, it didn't hit me because it had worked onload without it.